# Polymer : this.$[elementId] is undefined

Tags: polymer

Here is a simple polymer element which just access an inner element using its id and `this.$.[elementId]`, and then log it. Running, this simple code, you will be able to see that the returned element `undefined`. Why?

```
<dom-module id="custom-element">
  <template>
          <template is="dom-if" if="[[condition]]">
             <div id="main"></div>
          </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    class CustomElement extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return "custom-element"; }
            static get properties() {
                return {
                   condition : Boolean
                };
            }

            ready(){
                super.ready();
                console.log(this.$.main); // logs "undefined"
            }
    }
    
    customElements.define(CustomElement.is, CustomElement);
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Polymer `this.$` only references elements **from local DOM** which are not added dynamicly. Thus, **elements placed inside `dom-if` or `dom-repeat` templates are not added to the `this.$` object**.

If you wish to select a dynamic element you need to go to the dom and use something like `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#main')`

---

#### Here's a solution to get rid of this problem. Add the following code in your `ready()`:

```
if (this.$)
    this.$ = new Proxy(this.$, {
        get: ($, id) => $[id] || this.shadowRoot.getElementById(id),
        set: ($, id, element) => {
            $[id] = element;
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me for elements inside dom-if in Polymer 2. If I move out element outside of dom-if it's returning results, but not when they are in dom-if.

Comment: That's exactly what I said in the answer. ^^